# Running into an illegal start of expression error while changing the value of an array

Tags: java, arrays

In a for loop I'm trying to change the contents of an array variable for one of my "Tile" classes. I keep getting an illegal start of expression error and I cant for the life of me figure out what's going wrong.

First off, I'll show you my class and the for loop where this is all going wrong.

```
class Tile {

    int value;
    int pos;
    Tile[] adj;

    public Tile(int value, int pos) {

        this.value = value;
        this.pos = pos;

    }
}
```

and the for loop in question:

```
public static void update(Tile[] arr) {

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        Tile t = arr[i];
        t.pos = i + 1;

        if(i == 0)
            t.adj = {arr[i]};
    }
}
```

So for each Tile I have an array called adj, but the compiler is not allowing me to define t.adj (where t is a Tile in the arr[] of Tiles). It's telling me that the first '{' curly bracket is an illegal start to the expression.

What's especially weird is that I can declare a test array right before it that won't run into any errors with the compiler:

```
if(i == 0)  {

    Tile[] testTile = {arr[i]};
    t.adj = {arr[i]};               //compiler should know that this is an 
                                      array of tiles... but it doesn't?

}
```

The testTile doesn't run into any errors, so I know that it's not a matter of a loose semicolon. I'm really confused as to what the difference between these two statements is. I've already declared that adj is a an array of Tiles(as per the Class Tile). I declare the variable t as each Tile being processed in the method's argument array.

I've tried making the function not static, defining the default size for the adj[] array, but nothing is making the compiler cooperate. I've even tried setting t.adj = 5; but I get  this error:

```
    Main.java:105: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to 
                                     Tile[]
            t.adj = 5;
```

Which proves to me that the compiler recognizes t.adj as a Tile[] type.

What mystical Java rule am I breaking that isn't allowing the compiler to accept what I've written???

```
    Main.java:105: error: illegal start of expression
            t.adj = {arr[i]};
                    ^
    Main.java:105: error: not a statement
            t.adj = {arr[i]};
                        ^
    Main.java:105: error: ';' expected
            t.adj = {arr[i]};
                           ^
    Main.java:112: error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Comment: `t.adj = new Tile[] {arr[i]};`

Comment: "*...weird is that I can declare...*" - declare is the magic word here; declaration is not the same as assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the [*array initializer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) syntax on its own when declaring a variable. In this case, you're using it in an assignment expression to an existing variable, so you need to use an [*array creation expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1):

```
t.adj = new Tile[] { arr[i] };
```